# CosmosDb Sql query that matches common values in array between documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am working with Cosmos DB and I want to write a SQL query that will match common value in array of documents based on id.

To elaborate, imagine you have the following three documents:

```
{
        "id": "2ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39",
        "entityType": "ServiceInformationFacility",
        "facilities": [
            {
                "id": "6F706BA3-27AD-45B8-9831-A531E37C4C17",
                "facilityName": "Kat Service Center",
                "phoneNumber": "9879561234"

            },
            {
                "id": "7F706BA3-27AD-45B8-9831-A531E37C4C17",
                "facilityName": "Honda Service Center",
                "phoneNumber": "9879561234"

            }]

    },
    {
        "id": "3ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39",
        "entityType": "ServiceInformationFacility",
        "facilities": [
            {
                "id": "8F706BA3-27AD-45B8-9831-A531E37C4C17",
                "facilityName": "Hyundai Service Center",
                "phoneNumber": "9879561234"

            },
            {
                "id": "7F706BA3-27AD-45B8-9831-A531E37C4C17",
                "facilityName": "Honda Service Center",
                "phoneNumber": "9879561234"

            }]

    },
    {
        "id": "6ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39",
        "entityType": "ServiceInformationFacility",
        "facilities": [
            {
                "id": "8F706BA3-27AD-45B8-9831-A531E37C4C17",
                "facilityName": "Hyundai Service Center",
                "phoneNumber": "9879561234"

            },
            {
                "id": "7F706BA3-27AD-45B8-9831-A531E37C4C17",
                "facilityName": "Honda Service Center",
                "phoneNumber": "9879561234"
            } ]
    }
```

I want to write a query that return all the common facility based on id.That means when passing the list of Ids, the facility exists in the given Ids should be display(not either or).
so in the above collection it should only return "facilityName": "**Honda Service Center**" by passing parameter id("**2ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39**","**3ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39**","**6ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39**").

So far I have tried:

```
SELECT q.facilityName  FROM c
join q in c.facilities
where c.id in('6ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39','2ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39')AND c.entityType = 'ServiceInformationFacility'
```

It gives me all the facility name but I need only facility which are common in the above documents that is  "facilityName": "Honda Service Center".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It gives me all the facility name but I need only facility which are
>   common in the above documents that is "facilityName": "Honda Service
>   Center".

I may get your point now.However,i'm afraid that's impossible in cosmos sql. I try to count number of appearance of `facilitiesName` cross the documents and get below solution which is closest with your need.

sql:

```
SELECT count(c.id) as cnt, f.facilityName from c 
join f in c.facilities
where array_contains(['6ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39','2ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39'],c.id,true)
AND c.entityType = 'ServiceInformationFacility'
group by f.facilityName
```

output:

[image]

Then i tried to extend it with some [subquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery) but no luck. So i'd suggest using stored procedure to finish the next job.The main purpose is looping above result and judge if the `cnt` equals the `[ids array].length`.

---

Update Answer for Stored procedure code:

input param for @idArray:`["6ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39","2ECF4568-CB0E-4E11-A5CD-1206638F9C39"]`

[image]

Sp code:

```
function sample(idArray) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var length = idArray.length;

    var sqlQuery = {
        "query":  'SELECT count(c.id) as cnt, f.facilityName from c join f in c.facilities '+
        'where array_contains( @idArray,c.id,true) ' +
        'AND c.entityType = "ServiceInformationFacility" group by f.facilityName',
        "parameters": [
            {"name": "@idArray", "value": idArray}
        ]
    }

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        sqlQuery,
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var returenArray = [];
            for(var i=0;i<feed.length;i++){                
                if(feed[i].cnt==length)
                    returenArray.push(feed[i])
            }

            response.setBody(returenArray);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to hard code the facilityName in the query. It should display the common  facilityName among array based on Ids.

Comment: @Triptychauhan Please tell me if i misunderstand your requirement again.You want to get facilityName and remove all the duplicate items,am i right? Just use `distinct `operator in your sql.

Comment: Let me explain.There are three document mentioned above and among those three I need  facilityName which are common and exists in all the document. If you see among three document only honda service centre is common in all the document array.Same as intersect or inner join in sql to get the matching record.Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: @Triptychauhan Sorry for my previous misunderstandings and refer to my latest answer,if any concern,please let me know.

Comment: @Triptychauhan So,any updates here?Does my answer helps you?

Comment: Could you please help me with the store procedure code. I am struggling in writing the storeprocedure as I am new to cosmosdb and javascript. I need to check if your solution works for me.

Comment: @Triptychauhan Sorry for the late response,i will add some stored procedure code for you.

Comment: @Triptychauhan It seems that someone posts similar question to yours.I guess you have same target.So,maybe you could follow the updates i posted there.

Comment: Yes I saw the similar post.My Partition key is "entityType" mentioned in the document and when I passed the partition key value "ServiceInformationFacility" as string in partition key parameter and input parameter Ids while executing the sp, I got "no docs found" as output.

Comment: @Triptychauhan hi,as i said in this case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817894/substitute-for-having-clause-in-cosmosdb/59818791?noredirect=1#comment105777690_59818791, SP is not suitable any more if your collection is partitioned.Because you have to provide partition key so the result is scoped by the pk,you won't get right result. So,maybe you could try to use some code to implement the same logic.Hope i'm clear on this.